# Replace text inside tags in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Does anyone know if it's possible to replace text inside tags.

For instance...

"`If I had a row that contains this text, I would want this text to be outputted but I would want <hidden>This text to not be selected</hidden>`"

Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean that you want to replace the text between the two hidden tags?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to do some form of custom parsing on the value to remove those sections.

Performance-wise, that may not be great if you do it within TSQL. [SQLCLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28VS.80%29.aspx) may be something to try out for this (much better at string manipulation etc), or do that replacement outside of SQL altogether in the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

As the other two said, T-SQL is not the best way to do this.  If you REALLY want to though, for your  example you could do something like:

```
DECLARE @String varchar(1000)

SET @String = 'If I had a row that contains this text, I would want this text to be outputted but I would want <hidden>This text to not be selected</hidden>'

SELECT LEFT(@string, (CHARINDEX('<Hidden>',@string)-1)) + (RIGHT(@string, ((LEN(@String) -(CHARINDEX('</Hidden>', @String))))+1-(LEN('</hidden>'))))
```

This should be a good motivator to **NOT** do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

As per AdaTheDev it seems that SQLCLR is the way to go.  I did a quick google on [T-SQL regex](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=t-sql+regex&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) and turned up an MS link that confirms it for 2005.